# Finding a möbius transformation satisfying the following mappings

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a function f(z) = $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ satisfying the following:

O $\rightarrow$ i, 1 $\rightarrow$ 1, 
$\infty$ $\rightarrow$ -i

From the first condition I get that $b = id$
From the second I get that $a+b = c+d$
From the third I get that $a = -ic$

does that seem right?

Comment: yes. Now solve! (Answer is not unique.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Maybe you ask such question because you have 4 variables and only 3 equations([Underdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system))? Just let $a=1$ and solve the system of linear equations.